# How can I do a cloth simulation while the normals are flipped?

Tags: modeling, normals, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create a cloth simulated skirt around a low poly character model with a toon-style outline. However, I've run into a couple issues. Using the (I believe its called) inverted hull method, I was able to create a decent-looking outline, however it required me to flip the normals on my mesh to show up. I'm fairly new to this, so I just accepted what worked in the render preview.

But... when I do a cloth sim, the fabric goes INSIDE the mesh. I get why, but is there any way around this?

I'm also concerned that when I add the toon outline on the skirt (once its done) that the flipped normals THERE will also mess with the sim. But I'll get to that part later.